# Is this effect possible in code?

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes

I noticed an interesting trend that designers follow for creating a sort of underline and I'm curious if this can be achievable in code. It's like an underline, but it goes behind the word.

[image]

Comment: what have you done so far? should we start writing the code for you?

Comment: Short answer yes it can

Comment: yes this can be easily achieved in code, in many different ways. if you post some sample code we can help

Comment: Your question should probably be: _"How do I do this with CSS?"_ since, as you've noticed, the answer to _"can it be done"_ is _yes_.

Comment: Ok, didn't expect the downvotes. My first try was to reduce the line-height and use a thick border-bottom, but this would mean that the edges would be square and I was more curious about the round edges of that border, if they can be possible to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in a much shorter way:

```
.underline {
  font-size: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 255px;
  box-shadow: 0 45px 0 5px #D9EEC3;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/vohoroziwa/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

For best practice, you should share your code. From the image and question, you can achieve it this way.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.heading {
  color: #404C64;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  line-height: 0.4;
}
.heading:after {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background: #D9EEC3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading">Text here</h1>
```

Comment: This is the one. Didn't believe it was possible. I was expecting for it to be a case of "dribbblisation". Thank you for sharing the code!

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>Text Here</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;

  /*  Adjust below values accordingly */
  padding: 0 15px;
}

h1:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;

  /*  Adjust below values accordingly */
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh7quap5/30/)